# Including external JavaScript file into jsp file getting some error

Tags: javascript, jsp, tomcat

Javascript file is not including into **JSP** file. when I am trying to see it firebug I am getting below error one html tab and in javascript tab no file is present.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.63 - Error report

## HTTP Status 404 -

**type** Status report

**message**

**description** The requested resource is not available.

#### Apache Tomcat/7.0.63

Comment: `404` is a fairly standard and well understood error message. That URL you are asking for was not found by the server. What more do you expect us to say given the information in the question?

Comment: The file isn't found. Check your path or URL.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got the solution. I was giving wrong path name during file include. I put below code into jsp and finally js is including

```html
<head>
  <script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/jquery-1.2.6.min.js" />"></script>
    <script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/pass_mask_v0.1.js" />"></script>
</head>
```